# How to overwrite a key binding only on eshell?

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings, evil-mode, eshell

I use `evil-mode` on emacs, and recently I started using `eshell`, I really like how I can leave insert mode and move on the `eshell` buffer to copy content or other goodies, but when entering insert mode again it does it in the cursor current position, what I would like is that when I enter insert mode automatically move the currsor to the prompt line (last line, end of line).

What I did was:

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
      (lambda()
         (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "i") (lambda () (interactive) (evil-goto-line) (evil-append-line nil)))))
```

However it applies this mapping in all other buffers, I just want to make it active on an eshell buffer.

**How to define a key binding that works differently in eshell?**

Comment: Does this link help any?:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26587651/2112489  Perhaps there are some other evil local maps you can use.  I don't use evil, but that's the general idea -- i.e., using local stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37232411/8468492) satisfies the stated requirements, but has two major limitations:

1. It only triggers when entering insert mode with <kbd>i</kbd>.
   Jumping to the last line with <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, or any custom functions/keybindings would require additional scripting.
2. If `point` is already on the last line (e.g., when editing the current command), there is no way to enter insert mode at the current position;
   <kbd>i</kbd> is effectively rebound to <kbd>A</kbd>.

The first limitation can be eliminated by hooking first on `eshell-mode` then second on `evil-insert-state-entry`.

The second limitation can be addressed by setting `point`'s position based first on the line number and second on the read-only [text-property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html):

1. If `point` is not already on the last line, then it is moved to `point-max` (which is always read-write).
2. Otherwise if the text at `point` is read-only, `point` is moved to the position in the current line where the read-only text-property changes.

The following code negates the limitations of the accepted answer.

```lisp
(defun move-point-to-writeable-last-line ()
  "Move the point to a non-read-only part of the last line.
If point is not on the last line, move point to the maximum position
in the buffer.  Otherwise if the point is in read-only text, move the
point forward out of the read-only sections."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((curline (line-number-at-pos))
         (endline (line-number-at-pos (point-max))))
    (if (= curline endline)
        (if (not (eobp))
            (let (
                  ;; Get text-properties at the current location
                  (plist (text-properties-at (point)))
                  ;; Record next change in text-properties
                  (next-change
                   (or (next-property-change (point) (current-buffer))
                       (point-max))))
              ;; If current text is read-only, go to where that property changes
              (if (plist-get plist 'read-only)
                  (goto-char next-change))))
      (goto-char (point-max)))))

(defun move-point-on-insert-to-writeable-last-line ()
  "Only edit the current command in insert mode."
  (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook
        'move-point-to-writeable-last-line
        nil
        t))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
      'move-point-on-insert-to-writeable-last-line)
```

Comment: But is there a way to make it impossible to enter insert mode in the middle of the shell prompt? Have you ever used `:term` in neovim? that's exactly what I want in eshell, it doesn't let you modify things you shouldn't.

Comment: @ZzAntáres I have not yet found out how to detect if the point is in a read-only part of a buffer.  Once I have discovered how to do so I intend to update my code and my answer to this question.

Comment: @ZzAntáres [Revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46937891/revisions) of the answer addresses entering insert mode in the shell prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @lawlist for pointing me in the right direction, the solution is just as easy as:

```
;; Insert at prompt only on eshell
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (define-key evil-normal-state-local-map (kbd "i") (lambda () (interactive) (evil-goto-line) (evil-append-line nil)))))
```

Thanks!

Comment: You almost never want to quote a lambda form like that, as it can't be byte-compiled.  `lambda` is self-quoting (with `function`), so just remove the `'`. (Also not the best idea to put a lambda form on a hook variable at all, as updating such values is usually awkward. Named functions are easier to maintain.)

Comment: Thanks! didn't know that!, so this is not byte compiled? `(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'(lambda () (setq gc-cons-threshold 800000)))`

Comment: `(lambda ...)` and `#'(lambda ...)` are equivalent, both quoted with `function` (implicitly and explicitly respectively). `'(lambda ...)` is different, being quoted with `quote` and thus cannot be byte-compiled.